# How to delete a character by using visual block?

Tags: vim

I normally use `visual block` to insert a semicolon at the end of the lines by using: `<Ctrl-v>G$A;<Esc>`. This works very well. However, when I wanted to delete the semicolons by using the similar keystrokes, `<Ctrl-v>G$A<BS><Esc>`, it worked only the first line as following:

**Result:**

```
var foo = 1
var bar = 'a';
var baz = 'z';
var foobar = foo + bar;
var foobarbaz = foo + bar + baz;
```

**Expected result:**

```
var foo = 1
var bar = 'a'
var baz = 'z'
var foobar = foo + bar
var foobarbaz = foo + bar + baz
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: ftr - I switched to using `:%norm A;` to append to every line. It just works a bit better for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is why this happens:
That is basically, because Vim does not know what to do, once the edited text gets shorter than the original line, so it aborts the block edit.

I have wanted to fix this to, but haven't found a good solution for this problem yet.

Comment: Thanks for your response. At least I knew the reason from your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Is a visual range plus a command sufficient?

```
:<','>norm $x
```

Would run `$x` (delete the last character on the line) on every line in the visual selection.

Comment: Yes, this will work as expected. It's just my curious why the `Visual block` doesn't work in the same way as inserting a character.

Comment: @LVarayut I assume its because its supposed to append a string to the end of the line. And deleting a character isn't actually a string.